# ¿Cómo crear una columna en SQL para almacenar mes y año?

Tags: sql

¿Hay alguna forma de definir un tipo DATE que solo recoja en base de datos el mes y el año? Sin tener que hacer ninguna ñapa.

Un saludo

Comment: No existe ninguna fecha que no tenga día. Los campos de tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME` son para almacenar fechas con días. Luego en la consulta puedes sacar sólo el día, o sólo el mes, o sólo el año, o sólo el mes y el año, o sólo el día y el año´o sólo el día y el mes, de **esa fecha**. Son dos cosas distintas el dato en sí y la forma en que quieres presentarlo. Esa es la ventaja de los campos de tipo fecha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo único que se me ocurre es que crees un campo con `date` normal, y cuando hagas el select puedes  hacer un `WHERE YEAR(tabla.columna) = 2018 AND MONTH(tabla.columna) = 1` ignorando los días

Comment: También puedes crear dos columnas `mes` y `anyo` y usarlas para hacer el select, porque otra maera no hay.

Comment: Gracías, lo dejaré como DATE normal y meteré el filtro cuando realice una consulta.